# Warning: RPMDB altered outside of yum hangs on rpm install

Tags: bash, shell, centos, rpm, yum

I just created rpm package which contains few shell scripts and My rpm executes those shell scripts in post installation step ( i.e %post section). 
My RPM is created successfully and when I run 
`rpm -ivh myrpmfile.rpm` RPM able to find my shell scripts and running them properly. Those scripts also install few other packages with yum so when yum try to install those packages it hangs with the following error

> Warning: RPMDB altered outside of yum

Sometimes it hangs at the following state.

- Running transaction check
- Running transaction test
- Transaction test succeeded
- Running transaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call `yum` from your `%post` because the database is locked. If you need other packages installed, you set them as `Required`. If your RPM also installs the yum repo files, then you need to make them into two RPMs.

That warning is just because you used `rpm` directly "behind its back" and most likely is a red herring.